# Chartjs v3 no title text gets displayed

Tags: node.js, typescript, chart.js

I am using [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas) together with chart.js v3.9.1 to generate a chart. At first, my chart had a title text displayed but after I was done modifying the options the title will not be displayed anymore. I *think* I configured the title right but why isn't it working?

Here are the options I use:

```
{
    "type": "line",
    "data": {
        "labels": [
            "2024-01-11",
            "2024-01-31",
            "2024-02-01",
            "2024-02-15",
            "2024-02-16"
        ],
        "datasets": [
            {
                "label": "Data 1",
                "borderColor": "rgb(75,+192,+192)",
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(75,+192,+192,+.5)",
                "data": [
                    4356338,
                    222493,
                    2582350,
                    119649
                ],
                "yAxisID": "y",
                "type": "line",
                "order": 0
            },
            {
                "label": "Data 2",
                "borderColor": "rgb(255,+99,+132)",
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,+99,+132,+.5)",
                "data": [
                    3,
                    1,
                    1,
                    0
                ],
                "yAxisID": "y1",
                "type": "bar",
                "order": 10
            },
            {
                "label": "Data 3",
                "borderColor": "rgb(54,+162,+235)",
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(54,+162,+235,+.5)",
                "data": [
                    2374930,
                    514387,
                    1413894,
                    64462
                ],
                "yAxisID": "y",
                "type": "line",
                "order": 0
            },
            {
                "label": "Data 4",
                "borderColor": "rgb(255,+205,+86)",
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,+205,+86,+.5)",
                "data": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "yAxisID": "y1",
                "type": "bar",
                "order": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    "options": {
        "title": {
            "display": true,
            "text": "Chart.js Line Chart"
        },
        "scales": {
            "x": {
                "title": {
                    "text": "Date",
                    "display": true
                }
            },
            "y": {
                "title": {
                    "text": "Count",
                    "display": true
                },
                "display": true,
                "position": "left",
                "ticks": {
                    "precision": 0
                }
            },
            "y1": {
                "title": {
                    "text": "Count",
                    "display": true
                },
                "display": true,
                "position": "right",
                "grid": {
                    "drawOnChartArea": false
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "precision": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Together with this function to get the image as buffer:

```
const chartBuffer = await new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width: 500, height: 300 }).renderToBuffer(this.chartOptions);
```

Comment: In chart.js v3.9.1 the title configuration is under `options.plugins.title` (not under `options.title` as in the older/original version), see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/configuration/title.html)